# Why am I getting a 404 Error when deploying to Vercel?

Tags: express, deployment, vercel

I just finished a coding boot camp and am trying to deploy one of my projects to Vercel.  This is a JavaScript app uses Express.js. Previously, the project used Heroku.  The project works on Heroku.  However, when I attempt to deploy to Vercel, I receive the following error:

404: NOT_FOUND
Code: NOT_FOUND
ID: cle1::fkgf5-1708983724776-48543a302b5d

Thank you so much!

I added in a vercel.json file that looks like this:
`{ "rewrites": [ {"source": "/(.*)", "destination": "/"} ] }`

However, this didn't solve the problem.

I am also aware of changing the Framework Preset in the Vercel Build and Deployment Settings.  I just don't know what to pick there other than 'Other'.  My app doesn't appear to use any of those technologies.  This is an Express app that doesn't use React, Vite, or Next.js.

I am happy to provide code to assist with solving the issue.  However, at this time, I am unsure of what code I should be providing.

Thank you